How can I automate checking of Google Sheets to see if each sheet has been authorized by the user?
I have multiple google sheets that need authorized by the user each time they are copied, so that the scripts can run. Is there a way through a script to check to see if each sheet has been authorized by the user?
I have tried running this script but it reports false data:
function checkAuthorizationForSheetsFromTab() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('New'); // Get the "New" sheet
var urlRange = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow()); // Get all URLs in column A
var urls = urlRange.getValues(); // Get the values as a 2D array

var results = \[\]; // Array to store authorization results for writing to column C

// Loop through each URL in column A
urls.forEach(function(row, index) {
var url = row\[0\]; // Get the URL from the first column of each row
var isAuthorized = false; // Default to false if not authorized or if there's an error

    if (url) {  // Check if the URL is not empty
      try {
        // Try to open the sheet by its URL
        var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    
        // Try accessing a protected property (e.g., sheet name)
        var sheetName = targetSheet.getName();
    
        // If no error occurs, the script is authorized for this sheet
        Logger.log('Authorized access for sheet: ' + url);
        isAuthorized = true;
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle authorization or other errors
        if (e.message.includes('Authorization')) {
          Logger.log('Script is not authorized for sheet: ' + url);
        } else {
          // Log any other errors (e.g., invalid URL)
          Logger.log('An error occurred with sheet: ' + url + ' - ' + e.message);
        }
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No URL found in row ' + (index + 1));
    }
    
    // Push the result (TRUE or FALSE) to the results array
    results.push([isAuthorized]);

});

// Write the results to column C
var resultRange = sheet.getRange(1, 3, results.length, 1); // Column C, from row 1 to the last row
resultRange.setValues(results);

Logger.log('Authorization results have been written to column C.');
}


Explain "false data" in detail

Would you please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and then edit the question to include all relevant information including sample data and an example of successful outcome(s).  As it stands, users are unable to test or trouble-shoot any code because of a lack of data.

Users cannot grant authorizations on a per-spreadsheet basis, because authorizations are always granted per script project. The distinction is not always easy to make, because many scripts are implemented as container-bound script projects where the document or spreadsheet "contains" the project, and because when a document or spreadsheet is copied, another copy of its script project gets created as well. Each project needs its own authorization to run under a particular user account.
To avoid the need to re-authorize the script project for every copy of a spreadsheet, implement the project as an add-on. They only need to be authorized once per user.
There appears generally to be not a small amount of confusion regarding the concepts of authorization and access rights.
Google Drive objects such as files and folders each have an access control list. Users and service accounts can be granted rights to view, edit and comment either directly, by being named in the access control list, or indirectly, through a group they are a member of.
When a script is run, it operates under a user account, and has the same access rights as that user. The account is usually that of the user at the keyboard, with these notes:

When the script or add-on is started interactively, such as through button, a custom menu item, a sidebar or through the Run button in the script editor, it runs under the account of the user at the keyboard.

When the script is started through an installable trigger, it runs under the account of the user who created the trigger.

When the script is deployed as a web app, it can be configured to "Execute the app as user accessing the web app", or as "Execute the app as me" which means that it runs under the account of the user who deployed the web app.


There are additional exceptions related to simple triggers and custom functions, but the bottom line in the general case is: the script has access to the same objects as the user who runs the script.
The concept of script authorization is separate from access rights. Authorization determines what Apps Script methods a script can use.
For example, the SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl() method requires this scope:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

When you run or deploy a script project for the first time, you are presented with an authorization dialog box. Apps Script looks at the code and determines what scopes are required by the methods that appear in the code, and shows them all in a list. The above scope would be presented as:

See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets

When you grant the authorization, the script runs. If you do not grant the authorization, none of the functions in the script project can be run, because the script project lacks the authorization to run under your account. But you cannot grant an authorization that would apply to some specific spreadsheet file — it's all or nothing, and the rest is determined by access rights.
Here's an extract of the code in the question:

      try {
        var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
        // If no error occurs, the script is authorized for this sheet
      } catch (e) {
        if (e.message.includes('Authorization')) {
          Logger.log('Script is not authorized for sheet: ' + url);
        } else {


The code does not determine whether the script has been authorized by the user at the keyboard. We already know that the script is authorized simply because it is currently running.
The code doesn't determine whether any script project bounded to targetSheet has been authorized by the user at the keyboard either.
What the code determines is:

Has the user at the keyboard been granted access rights to targetSheet? If the user cannot access the file, no script that runs under their account can access the file either.

Does the script project the code is part of have authorization to use the SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl() method? The answer would usually be yes. The authorization can be omitted by leaving out a scope in the manifest, or by adding a @OnlyCurrentDoc pragma in the script project. You can make that happen by first authorizing the script, then editing the manifest or adding the pragma, and then running the script. In some cases, Apps Script will notice the change, and present the authorization dialog box again. In other cases, Apps Script will throw an error when the offending method is called.


If the user can access the file, any script that runs under their account can access the file as well, provided that no exception under #2 is in effect.
In the event the script project uses the /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */ pragma, the script project can only access current document or spreadsheet. That is presented in the authorization dialog box like this:

View and manage spreadsheets that this application has been installed in

To properly determine whether another script project can currently be run by the user at the keyboard, use the Apps Script API.
